# Disable bluetooth in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: kubuntu, bluetooth, kde4

Does anyone know how to permanently disable bluetooth in Kubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a simple script and load it on start-up to disable bluetooth permanently.

- Open your editor using `gksudo kate` and copy this in it.

  `#!/bin/bash 
  rfkill block bluetooth`
- Save it under `/etc/init.d` with `<any_name>.sh`.
- Now make it executable using `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/<script_name>.sh`.
- Now use following command `sudo update-rc.d
  /etc/init.d/<script_name>.sh defaults`.

It will disable your bluetooth on system startup.

Comment: It cannot find the command +x

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: when I enter the last command it tells me that file does not exist

Comment: have you replace the `<script_name>` with the name of your script. I mean suppose you  have saved your scrpit with the name `bluetooth.sh` then use last command like this. `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/bluetooth.sh`.

Comment: Ok I entered the last command and it updated without errors but after reboot bluetooth is still on.

Comment: Is there `.` after `rfkill block bluetooth` in your script ?

Comment: Yes I put a . but nothing happens. With this #! in front /bin/bash the line is grey. Is it supposed to be like that? (never done scripting before).

Comment: Do not put any dot, just copy and past the above in your script without any dot.

Comment: removed the dot but again bluetooth is on after reboot.

Comment: OK, Here is another solution , save the script to `~/.kde/Autostart` folder and assing it executable permission using `chmod +x ~/.kde/Autostart/<script_name>.sh`.

Comment: Ok did that and this time it worked. I double checked through tlp and it says bluetooth = off (software).

Answer (score 1):

Better try and type  this in your terminal

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

Hope it disables the bluetooth

for unblocking use

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

If it shows access denied to rfkill then use

```
sudo rfkill block bluetooth
```

Comment: I entered the command and rebooted my laptop but the bluetooth icon says its on.