# How do you disable Bluetooth from terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: bluetooth

How do you disable Bluetooth from terminal in Ubuntu

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable bluetooth in Kubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/515335/disable-bluetooth-in-kubuntu-14-04)

Comment: @Hunter Not really a dupe. Its about Kubuntu. This is about Ubuntu

Comment: @UniKitty the difference is in the GUI. Why would it matter for a command line question?

Comment: Can you post the results of `lsusb` as I know another method that works

Answer (score 21):

To stop :

```
sudo service bluetooth stop
```

To start again:

```
sudo service bluetooth start
```

To restart :

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

To check current status:

```
service bluetooth status
```

---

Or you can use [`rfkill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rfkill) command:

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

Comment: @downvoter!!! WHY?

Comment: Someone doesn't like you. But I can't upvote or downvote, since I don't have Ubuntu. Do you think this will work on a tablet?

Comment: yes it should be

Comment: I need to set up a chroot with ubuntu and a USB bluetooth adapter to test. Or try a VM.

Answer (score 6):

You can also disable single adapters like

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 down
```

If `hci0` is the only adapter, this means bluetooth is unavailable then.

Comment: Would that switch the dongle mode to HDI and be able to use it on boot?

Comment: I would not expect any of the proposed solutions to cause that.

Answer (score 3):

Try this command:

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

Comment: +1 And `rfkill unblock bluetooth` to reenable.

Answer (score 2):

Also if you want to disable it permanently:

```
sudo mv /etc/init/bluetooth.conf /etc/init/bluetooth.conf.disabled
```

To re-enable:

```
sudo mv /etc/init/bluetooth.conf.disabled /etc/init/bluetooth.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

on more recent ubuntu, bluetooth can be controlled with:
`bluetoothctl power off` and `bluetoothctl power on`

This method doesn't require root privileges, and also the changes are immediately visible on the gnome bluetooth applet.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu version `20.04`:

**disable bluetooth service:**

```
#disable bluetooth service
sudo systemctl disable bluetooth

#stop running instance
sudo systemctl stop bluetooth
```

**re-enable service later:**

```
#re-enable bluetooth service later
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
 
#start bluetooth service again
sudo systemctl start bluetooth
```

Comment: Can you add a few more explanations? Also, giving how to restart / re-enable it is a good tip

Comment: This does not actually work, despite not throwing an error on the command line.

Comment: @Lexible: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @MD.MohiuddinAhmed 20.04

Comment: @Lexible: Any output on `journalctl` Or `dmesg |grep -i blue` ?